# Divide Ipl image by a scalar in OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to divide 2 by all the matrix elements of an Ipl image using cvDiv with C API of OpenCV. My code is as follows:

```
IplImage* src = cvLoadImage(argv[1]);

CvMat*  src1 = cvCreateMat(src->height, src->width, CV_16UC3);

cvDiv(src, src1, double scale=2);
```

But, I am getting the following error:

```
  error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
```

Can anybody tell why? Or is there any other way to divide all the elements of a matrix by a particular number say 2?

Comment: Do you have to use C or are C++ answers also welcome since, using C with openCV is getting deprecated(but still functional)?

Comment: using C is more preferable, as my whole project is written in C moreover for C++ the code is C++: void divide(double scale, InputArray src2, OutputArray dst, int dtype=-1), which is easier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this. But as I said it is quite diffucult and verbose to do this in the C-api but it is possible. In openCV C-Api it is really important that the matrices of the images are of the same type. Therefore you will not be able to do this with your

```
CvMat*  src1 = cvCreateMat(src->height, src->width, CV_16UC3);
```

but try it like this this works like a charm on my machine.

```
IplImage* src = cvLoadImage(argv[1]);
/*This ensures you'll end up with an image of the same type as the source image.
 *and it also will allocate the memory for you this must be done ahead.*/
IplImage* dest = cvCreateImage(
        cvSize(src->width, src->height),
        src->depth,
        src->nChannels
        );

/*we use this for the division*/
IplImage* div= cvCreateImage(
        cvSize(src->width, src->height),
        src->depth,
        src->nChannels
        );
/*this sets every scalar to 2*/
cvSet( div, cvScalar(2,2,2), NULL);
cvDiv( src, div, dest, 1 );
```

The above will get the job done using the C-api the same can be achieved with the following code using the C++-api and this is what I would recommend to anyone starting with opencv since I feel the C-api is much more verbose, and difficult. C++ matrix contructors and operator overloading make the task almost trivial:

```
cv::Mat Src2 = cv::imread( argv[1] );
cv::Mat Dest2 = Src2 / 2;
```

Comment: @hetepaperfan I am bit confused about code. What does your code does - divides []/4 or 4/[]? As, I want []/4.

Comment: @user227666 the `src` image is loaded from the file you specify. the `dest` image is preallocated to be of the same type and dimensions as the source. then we create an entrire matrix again in the same dimension and depth as the source called `div` every element is set to a scalar value I edited to be 2 as in you original question. then we divide elementwise every scalar in an image and put the result in dest. This is how a scalar division is done in C opencv.

Comment: @hetepaperfan yeah this seems fine so it does src/4 or 4/src?

Comment: @user227666 yes but of course in `cvScalar()` you can put other colors/values to do wat you want, this code make the source image a bit darker assuming that is what you want.

Comment: @user227666 it stores src/4 in dest.

Comment: @heterpaperfan but here http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvSubS#void%20cvDiv%28const%20CvArr*%20src1,%20const%20CvArr*%20src2,%20CvArr*%20dst,%20double%20scale%29 it is written it is doing {dst(I) = saturate(scale/src2(I))}
 means 4/src

Comment: @user227666 try to show the images using highgui, then you can see what it does, sometimes that just make things a little bit more clear.

Comment: I voted your answer and marked it as correct as it solved the problem mentioned but I misunderstood the function

Comment: @heterpaperfan when I displayed the image it's coming totally black

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34621/discussion-between-hetepeperfan-and-user227666)